# Sharepoint Alerts Have Wrong URL

Tags: sharepoint, wss-2.0

We are having an issue with Sharepoint alerts in version 2.0 of Windows Sharepoint Services. The link being sent in the alerts look like: "http://wws02 - Client Name", which is the server name instead of the client url (sharepoint.clientname.com). Anyone have any ideas on how to modify this url without affecting other sites being hosted on the same instance of WSS2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably better off on ServerFault but here goes

When you setup an Alert in SharePoint the URL is stored in the content database as absolute URL’s and using the URL of the page you were using at the time - in this case your server name.

http://sharepointalert.info/2009/10/troubleshooting-url-alert-email-incorrect/

You can change this in WSS3 using the updatealert command - but this isn't available for WSS2

Microsoft provide some [code that does the same thing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936760) which you may be able to modify to use in WSS2

There are also examples of [updating the urls in the content database](http://trycatch.be/blogs/tom/archive/2008/05/12/alerts-don-t-work-after-url-change.aspx) that you may be adapt for use with WSS3. Before someone jumps in screaming 'danger' ;) this has obvious dangers and will be unsupported by MS so use at your own risk.

Comment: Probably right that it belongs on serverfault. I ended up handing this off to one of our network engineers.